# AngularJS $http url placeholders not being placed with real data

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angular, and am having an issue where my $http url placeholders are not being replaced by the actual data. What I want is for this:

```
"/json/:searchType/:userId"
```

To be replaced with this when I use my $http call:

```
"/json/user/123"
```

Instead, I get something like this, according to firebug's Net tab:

```
"/json/:searchType/:userId?userId=123&searchType=user"
```

I have tried to create a fiddle, but because I use different views and json data from a server, I'm not sure how to create something that works in the fiddle that still looks anything like what I am actually doing. I have looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17021626/angularjs-query-url-parameter-not-set), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17376890/angular-js-full-example-of-get-post-delete-put-client-for-a-rest-crud-backend), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16648934/routing-trouble-in-angular-nodejs-angular), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313971/at-sign-in-parameter-names-in-resource-definition/13314014#13314014), and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559515/what-is-id-as-passed-to-resource), to name a few. I'm having trouble finding a posting that isn't about $resource, or the @ notation it uses to link url params to object params though.

To explain, I'm using a service to pass the `searchType` and `accountId` params between controllers and my factory, which actually performs the $http request.

Here is my controller:

```
.controller('UserDetailsCtrl', ["$scope", "Search", function ($scope, Search) {
    $scope.result = Search.getUser();
}])
```

Here is my Factory:

```
.factory('Search', ["$http", "SearchCriteriaSvc", function($http, SearchCriteriaSvc) {

    var baseUrl = "/json/:searchType/:accountId";

    return {
      getUser: function () {
        return $http.get(baseUrl,
                  {params:
                      {
                        accountId: SearchCriteriaSvc.getAccountId(),
                        searchType: SearchCriteriaSvc.getSearchType()
                      }
                })
                .then(function(result) {
                  return result.data;
                }); 
      }
    }
  }])
```

Finally, my service:

```
  .service('SearchCriteriaSvc', function() {
    var searchType = "",
        userId = "";

    return {
        getSearchType: function () {
            return searchType;
        },
        setSearchType: function(value) {
            searchType = value;
        },
        getUserId: function () {
            return userId;
        },
        setUserId: function(value) {
            userId= value;
        }
    };
  })
```

I have tried not using the service to pass the params (just manually typing in strings) and I get the same result, so I don't think that my service is the issue, but then, I'm at a loss.

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$http doesn't work in that way. You will have to collate your parameters into a URL yourself. 
You are probably thinking of $resource which allows you to predefine HTTP request URLs and their parametric components, or $route which also allows similar parametric URL functionality but within the context of your angular front end rather than back end. 
Any params passed in the way you pass them will end up as query / GET style parameters.

[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http)

```
params – {Object.<string|Object>} – Map of strings or objects which will be turned to ?key1=value1&key2=value2 after the url. If the value is not a string, it will be JSONified.
```

Comment: You are right - I can't believe I missed that. Thank you for the quick help!